# Быстрее ли работают сложение/вычитание и битовые операции по сравнению с делением/умножением в SIMD?

Tags: c++, x86, simd

Как известно, обычные инструкции сложения/вычитания и битовых сдвигов в процессорах x86 работают быстрее, чем инструкции умножения/деления. По-этому, для повышения производительности, операции *,/ как правило по возможности стараются заменить на +,-,>>,<<.

Мой вопрос: верно ли это утверждение для команд SIMD-расширений, как например SSE2? Или все инструкции SSE2 или другого расширения выполняются за равное количество тактов, а значит с заменой, скажем, операции деления на битовые сдвиги со сложениями можно не париться?

Answer (score 7):

Важно понимать, что:

1. Современный компилятор достаточно умен и сообразителен, чтобы делать такие замены самостоятельно. Если вы делаете их вручную в ущерб читаемости кода просто в процессе написания, вы делаете только хуже. Потому что нечитаемый код может нанести экономических и репутационных потерь больше, чем гипотетические 2-3-5 процентов потери скорости, существование которых экспериментально не доказано.
2. Прагматичный подход к оптимизации идет от лога профайлера, а не от того, что вы что-то где-то слышали от кого-то или даже читали, даже в учебнике, даже в именитом. Times, they are changing. Рекомендашки по ускорению устаревают раз в три года, а через пять лет покрываются плесенью. В олдскульных книжках, например, можно прочесть, что по массивам лучше ходить задом неперед из-за инструкции `loop`, которая отматывает регистр `CX` до нуля. Ага, советы из 80х, транслируемые преподами ВТУЗОВ студентам 2020х
3. Время выполнения инструкции в современном конвейерном SIMD процессоре, который еще перегоняет у себя CISC в RISC внутри, зависит от большого сочетания факторов, которые теоретически трудно предсказать. Главными является ширина кэш-линий, число свободных каналов памяти, мгновенная тактовая частота, зависящая от режима энергопитания и температуры *в данный момент времени (см. Turbo Boost и аналоги)*. Побочным может выступить такой фактор как внезапное попадание данных в другой NUMA-регион.
   Последним процессором, для которого можно было это четко узнать из мануала (была прямо табличка - опкод | число тактов) был не то `i386`, не то `i486`

**Вывод.** В каждом конкретном случае требуется проводить профилирование, на основании которого сравнивать полученную производительность с той, которую дает процессор на стандартных тестах LAPACK и похожих. Портить код, заменяя умножения на сдвиги смысла скорее всего нет вообще, потому что это сделает за вас компилятор. Если вы ему не доверяете, посмотрите машинный листинг, сделав его самостоятельно, или воспользовавшись онлайн-инструментом.

Comment: Я целиком согласен с первым утверждением. Всегда стараюсь найти компромисс между читабельностью и производительностью кода. Но там, где второе первому не мешает, предпочитаю всё же ручную оптимизацию. Конечно, без экспериментов с дизассемблированием, по-видимому, мне не обойтись, но всё же: _mm_div_epi16(a, const256), или _mm_srli_epi16(a, 8)? Это для примера вызовы.

Comment: Кстати, за весь мой скромный опыт реверсинга мне ни разу не попадались программы с инструкцией loop в обратных циклах. Всегда dec регистр/jnz метка. А однажды мне попалась программа с, о ужас, sub регистр,1 - похоже разработчики собрали её без оптимизации)))

Comment: @LShadow77, гугл в первых строках отправляет [к вот таким оценкам](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/343566/) (4 x 32 bit SSE integer mult оцениваются в 1 - 5 тактов, а обычное умножение в 1 - 7 тактов, в то время как, сложение и сдвиги и там и там оцениваются < 1 такта, **т.е. в принципе, те же  яйца, вид сбоку**)

Answer (score 6):

> Как известно, обычные инструкции сложения/вычитания и битовых сдвигов в процессорах x86 работают быстрее, чем инструкции умножения/деления.

Это скорее бабушка на двое сказала. Во-первых, "обычные инструкции" - это на самом деле целое семейство инструкций. Которые еще и по-разному реализованы в разных процессорах. Во-вторых, в целом у них сходная производительность (если мерять в тактах), в каких-то вариантах может быть быстрее допустим умножение, а в других сдвиг. Например (для  Sandy Bridge) IMUL m 2 CPI, SHL m,cl 4 CPI. При этом SHL r,i 0.5 CPI, а IMUL r,i 1 CPI. Для MMX psllw mm, mm и pmullw mm, mm - 1 CPI. Для SSE vpsllw ymm, ymm, xmm 1 CPI, а вот vpmulhw ymm, ymm, ymm на Skylake 0.5 CPI, а на более ранних те же 1 CPI. Вот деление да, оно гарантировано медленнее, там десятки CPI. В-третьих, собственно скорость вычисления в тактах - это далеко не единственная и не самая важная характеристика производительности инструкций. Если заглянуть в [каталог таких характеристик](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/reference/cpu-metrics-reference/assists.html), то там глаза разбегаются. В-четвертых, сложное устройство конвейера в современных процессорах также вносит свою лепту в определение производительности тот или иной инструкции, ведь реальная производительность варьируется в зависимости от состояния конвейера. Например идущие подряд 6-байтовые инструкции будут вызывать дополнительный простой.

Что касается парится или нет - парится надо, но делать это надо системно, а не пытаться сэкономить байты разбрасывая хитрые вставки в коде.